# Is there a torrent client which can force downloading consecutive segments of a file instead of random?

Tags: bittorrent

Basically I want to be able to download video files in a way that I can play them while they are downloading.

Or is that impossible to do with the bit torrent protocoll? If you can force the client to download certain files sooner can't you force it to download certain segments the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [uTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/). It has a streaming mode, so it will download segments sequentially. Some other bitTorrent client can do this as well. Note that download speed will be slower than usual.
Download the alpha which supports streaming from [here.](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=63247)

Comment: Are you talking about the 2.1 alpha which I read can preview videos with a web player? Because I can't find the option in the stable release

Comment: Yup, only the 2.1 alpha supports streaming.

Answer (score 1):

[BitComet](http://www.bitcomet.com/) supports this for a long time.
(Also, the download speed will be somewhat slower, expect that.)

Answer (score 1):

[qBittorrent](http://qbittorrent.sourceforge.net/) offers consecutive downloading as a per-torrent option. The option is straightforward and works as expected.

The program is cross-platform and lightweight, yet powerful. It is also **opensource** if it matters to you, and most Linux distros have packages for it.